# Сохранение данных пользователем. PHP+SQL

Tags: база-данных

Пользователь использует форму поиска по базе данных. Поиск происходит по категориям из двух таблиц (автор, жанр книги). После вывода результатов можно добавить определенный жанр(например, роман) или определенного автора(например, Пушкина ) в базу данных в таблицу интересы.

Для сохранения мне нужно указать идентификатор жанра или автора. Но ведь это две разные таблицу и id у них могут быть одинаковыми. Как мне определять, что выбранная категория это книга, а не жанр. И наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1** В таблице `интересы` должно быть два поля `ID автора`, `ID жанра` и заполнять одно из них (или оба, если меня интересуют конкретно стихи Пушкина)

**Вариант 2** Должно быть две таблицы: `Интересные жанры`, `Интересные авторы` и добавлять запись в одну из этих таблиц

Comment: А что если поиск выдаст несколько результатов из таблицы авторов. Ведь могут быть однофамильцы. Рядом с каждым именем будет кнопка добавления в таблицу интересов. Как мне присвоить кнопке определенный идентификатор? У меня получается, что все кнопки хранят только последний идентификатор, так как использую mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Так вы же не имя добавляете, а id. При чем здесь однофамильцы? ` У меня получается, что все кнопки хранят только последний идентификатор,` значит у вас где-то ошибка

Comment: Но я ведь ищу по имени. Мне выдает несколько результатов. Я с помощью функции mysqli_fetch_assoc() извлекаю данные, а после с присваиваю переменной $_SESSION идентификатор. Эту переменную я после сохраняю в таблице при нажатии на кнопку. Ведь у меня только одна переменная $_SESSION['id']. И получается, что все кнопки хранят только последний идентификатор.

Comment: А зачем вы перезаписываете значения? Почему вы не можете в `$_SESSION['id']` записать массив?

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] = []; $_SESSION['id'][] = mysqli_fetch_assoc();